# How do I use a magic spell in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Halloween 2013 and 2014 events feature [magic spells](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Magic_spells), which can be cast if the player equipped a Spellbook. I've done so, but how does one actually cast a spell?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I couldn't find an answer online because it's too abstract.

Comment: I have no idea, some frustrated user I guess.  +1 :)

Comment: @Studoku Rep only doesn't matter when you're way past the perks it gains. Anyway, this is a valid QA that would have saved me time had it been available sooner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Equip a Spellbook.
2. Collect a spell (glowing spellbook/crystalball item) from the map.
3. Consume the spell by pressing the key assigned to "Use Item in Action Slot" in the Options. The default is H.